# How to configurate nginx to redirect all responses to .php files to redirect on 404?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm using Ruby on Rails and so

How to configurate nginx to redirect all responses to .php files to redirect on 404?

Comment: Do you mean like redirect to a .php page on getting 404?

Comment: nope. I mean, if nginx get request to .php page — it should redirect it to 404 page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question (same as @dev0). If you want to send the user a 404 response when they try to *access* a php file, then put in a location block that will grab any php file and then do a simple `return 404;` statement in it.

```
location ~* ^.+\.php {
    return 404;
}
```

However, you'll need to do something different if you want to redirect a user to a specified PHP page when the user hits a 404 error. Is that it? And, if so, do you want to send them to one PHP page or a contextual PHP page? And do you want to pass arguments?

If you want to use a PHP page as a 404, then you can add the following to the main server block :

```
error_page   404 = /my_custom_404_page.php;
```

Comment: @shawn-patrik-rice, thanks for solution! what difference with
location ~ \.php$ {
    return   404;
}
?